# mongodb $elemMatch required with a single query condition

Tags: mongodb, null

I have some documents with nested arrays in Mongo (3.4.10):

```
> db.test.find()
{ "a" : [ ] }  // doc number 1
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] }  // doc number 2
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] }  // doc number 3
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] }  // doc number 4
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] }  // doc number 5
{ "a" : [ {  }, { "b" : 1 } ] }  // doc number 6
```

I tried a few queries, both with `$elemMatch` and without:

```
> db.test.find({'a.b':{$ne:null}})
{ "a" : [ ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] }
```

and

```
> db.test.find({a:{$elemMatch:{b:{$ne:null}}}})
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] }
{ "a" : [ {  }, { "b" : 1 } ] }
```

and

```
> db.test.find({'a.b':{$elemMatch:{$ne:null}}})
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] }
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] }
```

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) state that:

> If you specify only a single `<query>` condition in the `$elemMatch` expression, you do not need to use `$elemMatch`.

but these queries all return different results. I'm wondering why that is. I'd also like to know what exactly these queries are selecting for, because I can't quite make it out after experimenting and reading the docs about array queries and `$elemMatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a test databased and here's my line-by-line explanation of each output.

#### Query 1

```
db.test.find({'a.b':{$ne:null}})
```

Displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ ] } // doesn't contain b, so valid (mentioned by Sergey, see $ne docs)
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] } // has non-null b
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] } // has non-null b
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] } // has non-null b
```

Not displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ {  }, { "b" : 1 } ] } // find({'a.b':null}) matches, so discard
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] } // find({'a.b':null}) matches, so discard
```

See [`$ne` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne) for the first case.

The two undisplayed documents don't make much sense. They both have a single element which is accepted by `{$ne:null}`, which should make the whole document accepted.

Unfortunately, it is as I feared, Mongo takes the shortcut of simply running `find({'a.b':{$eq:null}})` ([source here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/5ab490e943395019a08ed088290aa462d8e310ad/src/mongo/db/matcher/expression_parser.cpp#L1533)), then takes all items **not** listed and returns them for `find({'a.b':{$ne:null}})`.

Try running `find({'a.b':{$not {$eq:null}}})` to see for yourself. This mishap is based on the idea that "not equal" is the inverse of "equal", which isn't true when a single true element makes the whole document true (e.g. `any(x!=3)` is not the same as `!any(x==3)`).

#### Query 2

```
db.test.find({a:{$elemMatch:{b:{$ne:null}}}})
```

Displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] } // non-null b
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] } // non-null b
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] } // non-null b
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] } // one element has non-null b
{ "a" : [ {  }, { "b" : 1 } ] } // one element has non-null b
```

Not displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ ] } // no elements, $elemMatch needs at least one element that matches
```

The trick here is that `$elemMatch` only considers cases where its `<field>` (`a` here) is [an array of ***one or more elements***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch). Only then it applies the predicate.

Thus it never even considers `{ "a" : [ ] }`, as it is an empty array. We see in this case there are non-null `b` fields for at least one element of array `a` in all remaining documents, and so those are accepted.

#### Query 3

```
db.test.find({'a.b':{$elemMatch:{$ne:null}}})
```

Displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] } ] } // a.b an array with 1+ elements
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 }, { "d" : 1 } ] } ] } // a.b an array with 1+ elements
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ { "c" : 1 } ] }, { "d" : 1 } ] } // a.b an array with 1+ elements
```

Not displayed:

```
{ "a" : [ ] } // a.b not an array with 1+ elements
{ "a" : [ { "b" : [ ] } ] } // a.b not an array with 1+ elements
{ "a" : [ {  }, { "b" : 1 } ] } // a.b not an array with 1+ elements
```

The trick here is again that `$elemMatch` only considers cases where its `<field>` is a non-empty array, but here `<field>` is `a.b` instead of `a`. The three documents not displayed do not meet this initial criteria and so are never tested. The remaining three documents all are non-empty arrays with more than 1 non-null element, so are all accepted.

#### Conclusion:

The `$elemMatch` docs are indeed misleading, they should state:

> If you specify only a single `<query>` condition in the `$elemMatch` expression, you do not need to use `$elemMatch`, *as long as `<field>` is an non-empty array.*

Even this doesn't quite make Queries 1 and 3 agree. This is because `$elemMatch` seems to force `{$ne:null}` to be evaluated once per element of `a.b` ([source here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/5ab490e943395019a08ed088290aa462d8e310ad/src/mongo/db/matcher/expression_parser.cpp#L1246)), whereas excluding it seems to apply `{$ne:null}` to the entirety of `a.b` at once.

I think Mongo should always apply `ne` element-wise, and doing otherwise seems like a bug. I've filed [a Jira Issue in Mongo](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31876) about this. Please vote it up to get this fixed.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much for writing it out. This bit me in production code so I wanted to make sure I fully understood this stuff.

Comment: Another related and (I think very) important point of confusion: when applied to a top-level field {$ne: null} does not match missing values. I use this all the time. When applies to nested (in an array and/or a dict I guess?) values, {$ne: null} seems to match missing values?! The $ne docs don't really mention this distinction at all either.

Comment: @nonagon hmm you’re right, I think I’ll mention that in my bug report as well

Comment: thanks for filing a bug report too - I sometimes think I've found a bug in mongodb but it's nearly always a mistake on my part, so I'm hesitant to file a report until I've gotten someone to confirm things

Comment: @nonagon no problem. Also I've found [the `explain()` function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) very useful if you don't already know about it.

Comment: @nonagon also bug report filed. See the link at the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1):

The first query will return documents *either* match criteria *or* do not have `b` field:

> $ne selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal
>   (i.e. !=) to the specified value. **This includes documents that do not
>   contain the field.**

In the second query, the element should exist before criteria is verified. If there are no elements, the document will not be returned:

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with **at least one element** that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

I believe it's a little mistake in $elemMatch documentation - they should have pointed that target field should exist in the document to have exactly same results.

Comment: Hmm that's tricky! A query on a top-level field x: {$ne:null} would return docs where x both exists and is not null, is that right? If so it seems like the {$ne:null} behavior is inconsistent when applied to arrays and/or embedded documents?

Comment: I added a 6th test case showing another important difference - I think something more is going on here, this is really confusing and inconsistent (or I'm missing something simple I suppose)